# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ApplicationUser' and 'string'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-identity

I'm using asp.net core Identity. The user ID will be as FK in the Invite model and I'm trying to display all the users that are in the invite

Models

```
    public class Invite
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]    //ICollection<Invite> in User 
        [Display(Name = "Users")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    }

=================

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("GameID")] 
        public int? GameID { get; set; }
        public string GameTag { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Invite> Invite { get; set; }

================
    public class Game
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Game")]
        public string GameName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }//Allow Users to get Games FKID (Foreign key ID)

    }
```

The getting the list of invites in the invite controller index and putting them inside viewbag for invite razor index page

this is where the error is coming from

```
if (i.User == tu.Id)
```

```
// GET: Invites
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            ViewBag.InviteList = new List<String>();
            var invite = _context.Invites;
            var theuser = _context.ApplicationUser;
            foreach (Invite i in invite)
            {
                foreach (ApplicationUser tu in theuser)
                {
                    if (i.User == tu.Id)
                    {
                        ViewBag.InviteList.Add(tu.GameID + " " +tu.GameTag);
                    }
                }
            }
            return View(await _context.Invites.ToListAsync());
        }
```

Comment: I would assume you're also missing the actual foreign key property, `UserId`, in your `Invite` model. With that, it would be `if (i.UserId == tu.Id)`

Answer (score 1):

Because `i.User` is an object of type `ApplicationUser`, it can't be compared to `tu.Id` which is (most likely) of type `int`.

You probably want to compare the IDs of the two `ApplicationUser`-Objects.

To do this, you need to use `i.User.Id == tu.Id` as the other comments have stated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant to compare this

```
if (i.User == tu)
{
}
```